# What is the influence of number of files on the bundle size of a React Native application?

Tags: react-native, bundle

The objective of my React Native application is as small bundle size as possible. And while looking for ways to keep the bundle size small, I came across this article [React Native Styling](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/structure-for-styling-in-react-native) suggesting ways to keep folders organized.

[image: Folder Structure Styles]

My question is does the number of js files have any influence on the bundle size. i.e., If I were to put a 20 lines of code in a single file(for example in index.js in the above example) as against 20 lines of code distributed in 4 files, will it affect the bundle size of the app. Because this issue is recurrent in other situations like in redux store if I could combine few reducers into a single file, or is the effect negligible?. I'm predefining code access and ease of maintenance as much lower priority than the app bundle size. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't. React Native generates a bundle from all your code which translates into one single file and it is well optimized for this problem.

You can use this visualizer to see what is taking space:
https://github.com/IjzerenHein/react-native-bundle-visualizer

The biggest issue most apps have regarding bundle size is not taking care of their dependencies. Coding everything in one file yourself will only hurt developer experience and maintainability.